# VueJS How to find specific elements in string and replace them

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I find and replace specific `html`-tags in `vue`? I have some `<b>` and `<i>`-tags which I want to replace with `<span>`-tags, but I haven't figured out how to do it.

For example, I tried this:

```
<button @click="replace">Replace</button>

data() {
  return {
    html: 'Lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b> sit amet, consectetur <i>adipiscing</i> elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <b>incididunt</b> ut labore et dolore magna aliqua'
  }
},
methods() {
  replace() {
     this.html.replace('b', '<span style="font-weight:bold">');
     this.html.replace('i', '<span style="font-style:italic">');
  }
}
```

but this does not work.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the approach in the original post. You might want to consult the details for [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

- The `replace` method does not modify the original string; it returns a new one. So

```
this.html = this.html.replace(/*...*/);
```

- You'll want to replace the entire tag, not just its name. So

```
this.html = this.html.replace("<b>", /*...*/);
```

- You need to replace the closing tags as well. So

```
this.html = this.html.replace("<b>", /*...*/).replace("</b>","</span>");
```

- You probably want to replace all of the tags, not just the first one. So

```
this.html = this.html.replace(/\<b\>/gi, /*...*/).replace(/\<\/b\>/gi,"</span>");
```

This approach won't work, of course, if the existing elements have any attributes